# Key hash format

Tags: facebook, react-native, openssl

I'm learning to make facebook apps and have come to the part where you have to enter your 28 character key hash.

I've searched the forums and internet after an answer but i couldn't find any. 
If someone does, please send me a link and i will close this thread.

I ran the code: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64 - in powershell, and it returns a 32 character code in this format: xxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx== I cant get what i'm doing wrong or how i'm supposed to translate this code to another format.

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by running the command in powershell instead of cmd.